# How to get rid of the left and top margins in css when using html2pdf

Tags: php, css, html2pdf

I'm using html2pdf and I want to get rid of the top and left margins using css but I can't.
Before output buffering margin is already set to 0, it works on html but when I convert it to pdf using [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) the top and left margins appears again.

Here's my current css.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#box {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 803px;
    height: 1400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: i recommednd not using link where you ask questions:)

Comment: @faq why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @pekka it is really not that complicated: if you have a website that converts doc2pdf you dont ask questions(or whitout sources) about how to converting doc2pdf. Its a repuattion thing

Comment: @faq what are you talking about? He is linking to the *product is he is using.* It's not his own site.

Comment: @pekka: i sad "i recommend" i wasent trying to be clever :)

Comment: @faq I understand, but in this case I think it's *great* that he posted a link. I wish everyone did when asking questions about a product, people most often don't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect that the margins are generated by html2pdf, not from the html/css. Have you tried to set the margins in the [html2pdf-constructor](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil#initalizing_the_html2pdf_class)?
E.g. with `array(0, 0, 0, 0)` as last parameter:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
```