# Odoo 10 Report Margin

Tags: odoo-10, html2pdf, qweb

I am working on small label and I am trying to use all the space but it seems to always add margin on the side of the report(Cannot remove it using styling or in page setting). I did some research and it seems to be html2pdf problem but I dont know how to do it in odoo. Do you have any suggestions how to remove the margin ? I've attached  link to the problem I found and image.

[image]

[How to get rid of the left and top margins in css when using html2pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769474/how-to-get-rid-of-the-left-and-top-margins-in-css-when-using-html2pdf)

Thanks

Comment: In css when you are not adding any design to the document then it will take default space. So to modify that you need to re-add the same css with your custom margin. In your case you need to remove margin give width:0px; that might help you.

Comment: Tried it, no luck, I've tried everything in css and the margin just stays the same.

Comment: Are there any margins on the paper format of the label report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In label printing wkhtmltopdf will add default margin, but you can fix it using following method.

```
<div class="page"  style="margin-left:-15px !important">  
</div>
```

In main div tag you can set default margin left based on that space will manage in report printing and you will not get extra space in left side same as you can do it for margin top as well.

This may help you.

Comment: Solved! Thanks !!